# How to prove that $max(\aleph_{0}, card(X)) = max(\aleph_{0}, card(L(X)))$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

I struggle with the following problem. Let $X$ be a set of elementary sentences and $L(X)$ be the smallest elementary language in which we can express all the sentences from $X$. How to prove that $max(\aleph_{0}, card(X)) = max(\aleph_{0}, card(L(X)))$?

I’m aware that for any elementary language L, $card(L) = card(Form(L)) = card(Sent(L)) = max(\aleph_{0},card(L))$, but I have no idea how to use it in a sensible way in establishing the desired equality.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is an elementary language and what are elementary sentences? Do you mean first order language and atomic sentences?

Comment: Can you define the terms "elementary sentence" and "elementary language"?

Comment: An elementary language is indeed a first-order language, an elementary sentence is a sentence in a first-order language (so it is a finite string over $L \cup V \cup \{ \neg, \wedge, \forall, = \} \cup \{),(\}$ -- that is L plus a countable set of variables plus a finite set of non-specific logical symbols and plus a finite set of auxiliary symbol -- of satisfying well-known properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L(X)$ is the first-order language generated by the symbols appearing in sentences in $X$. Let's denote this set of symbols by $\Sigma$. Then $|L(X)| = \max(\aleph_0,|\Sigma|)$.

Now each first-order sentence contains only finitely many symbols, so $|\Sigma| \leq |X|\cdot \aleph_0 = \max(\aleph_0,|X|)$. We have $$|L(X)| = \max(\aleph_0,|\Sigma|) \leq \max(\aleph_0,\max(\aleph_0,|X|)) = \max(\aleph_0,|X|).$$

Also, any first-order language is infinite, so $\max(\aleph_0,|L(X)|) = |L(X)| \leq \max(\aleph_0,|X|)$.

For the other direction, $X\subseteq L(X)$, so $|X|\leq |L(X)|$, and hence $\max(\aleph_0,|X|) \leq \max(\aleph_0,|L(X)|)$.

Comment: Could explain in more detail why $\Sigma \leq card(X) \cdot \aleph_{0}$?

Comment: Sure: we need an injection $\Sigma$ to $X\times \mathbb{N}$. If $\sigma\in \Sigma$, it appears in some sentence $\phi\in X$. Say $\sigma$ is the $n^\text{th}$ symbol appearing in $\phi$. Map $\sigma$ to $(\phi,n)$. This map is clearly one-to-one.

Comment: Good! Since this is only your second question here, maybe I'll point out that if you find an answer satisfactory, you can accept it by clicking the little check mark on the left (just in case you didn't know).